# How to play video player in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to implement jw player for video in iOS. how can i implement. i am using MPMediaplayer it is working for me. But i need to integrate on jwplayer for video in ios. how can  i do this thing. having any third party framework. is there any framework is there for iOS? or need to integrate any third party frameworks? please tell me..

```
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

mp.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

mp.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

mp.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self.view addSubview:mp.view]; //Show the view

mp.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

[mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Any body give me any idea plz tel me

Answer (score 0):

jwplayer has no sdk for ios, only for android. You can't use its in ios.

Comment: yaa i am already using Mediaplayer.framework.It is working fine for me. But i need to implement jwplayer

Comment: so tell me bro how can we implement jwplayer for video player in ios?

Comment: instead of jwplayer what i am using for video live streaming
?

Comment: You can use MPMoviePlayerController for stream, it not difficult. i recommend [ALMoviePlayerController](https://github.com/alobi/ALMoviePlayerController).(MPMoviePlayerController modification)

Comment: what is the Purpose of ALMoviePlayerController. i need video live streaming purpose..is it useful for live video streaming??